# Go Lang ioutil.writeFile function making directories and files read only

Tags: go

I have created a go program to trace over all the files under a root path and replace a specific source string with a target string after that writhing the updated content into the existing file and for that, I have used filepath.Walk function to trace over the files and ioutil.ReadFile and ioutil.WriteFile to read from and write into the file.
So, the problem is **ioutil.WriteFile** function  is marking the root directory, subdirectories, and files as read-only. I checked online for the solution of this but could not find anything appropriate.
Below is the code snippet of same.

```
if strings.Contains(data, sourceString) {
                    data = strings.ReplaceAll(data, sourceString, targetStringArray[index])
                    ioutil.WriteFile(path, []byte(data), os.FileMode(0655))
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

File mode 0655 is translated to permissions rw- r-x r-x. This combination of permissions is weird, because there is no "x" for the owner, but there are for the group and others. Maybe what you want is 0755 (rwx r-x r-x) for executable files or 0644 (rw- r-- r--) for non-executable files, which are the most used ones.

Comment: I have tried with permission 0777. But, the behavior was the same directories and files were getting marked as read-only.

Comment: If you try to change the permission manually (chmod 777 yourfile) with the same user that runs this Go executable, does it work? Maybe it's an OS restriction.